# SSL certificate related issue while calling rest servcies

Tags: rest, ssl

From client (eg: https://localhost:8080/) we are passing the certificate related values and calling the rest services ( hosted on different port - https://localhost:446/serviceName).

The issue is like, when we try to pass the certificate , SSL handshake is happening correctly (no error on debug) , but the certificate value is not passed to the service hosted on another port. Certificate value is accessed in server code by referring to (X509Certificate)httpReq.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

Note : We use Spring boot application which intenally runs on tomcat server.And desired CA authorised certificates, keystore and truststore are present in resource path in both the projects (client and service hosted). In rest service project config file, the client-auth is set to false.

Sample code snippet used to call rest service:

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(restserviceTruststore)
                    .loadKeyMaterial(restserviceKeyStore, password).build();

```
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()                    .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
                .setSslcontext(sslContext).build();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(XML, headers);
    response = restTemplate.postForObject(endpointURL, request, String.class);
```

Question:

1) From client what keystore and trustore should we need to pass to SSLContext? Is it server's keystore /truststore or clients?

2)What are the exact steps to be followed to resolve this issue.